# A circuit with resistors connected to the ground

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image: Resistors connected to grounds]

I do not understand how this circuit operates. As I know, for the current to flow through a circuit it should form a closed loop but I do not understand how this circuit forms a closed loop. In general, I got confused when I see a ground in the circuit. I do not know what the concepts that
I am missing regarding ground connections. I hope to find some helpful references.

Comment: Just run a wire connecting them all up, the grounds, so that the new wire is runs horizontally. That doesn't change the circuit. Now you should see better. But part of learning to read schematics is learning to see that connection, implicitly.

Comment: See if http://lednique.com/ground-earth-chassis/ helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ground symbol is a shorthand. Rather than drawing wires going all over a complicated schematic, we define a symbol that means "this point is connected to what we're going to call ground in this circuit". All of those symbols are connected together by definition--we just don't draw the wire so that the schematic is cleaner. In this case, it wouldn't make it very messy or confusing to draw the wire, but it absolutely would in a more complicated circuit.

Likewise, we often use an upward-pointing arrow with a label like "Vcc" or "+5V" or something to mean the same thing, except that it's the positive side of a power supply referred to ground. Since you'll probably have dozens or hundreds of things connected to that power supply in a complex circuit, this avoids extra wires running everywhere and makes it easier to understand the schematic. You can even use multiple such arrows, with one for Vcc and one for Vdd for instance; these will be connected to all other arrows with the same name.

If no power supply is drawn in the circuit, it can be assumed that a power supply is connected between a Vcc arrow and a ground symbol (and if the arrow is labelled +5V or something similar, you can assume the power supply is 5 volts); this is common on circuit diagrams that are meant to show something other than a complete schematic, like how to hook up a particular integrated circuit or the like.

Comment: We have a current source at the left side of the image. It's almost the same as a voltage source, just different ;)

Comment: @kruemi Yes, there's a power supply in this circuit, but I wanted to mention what would happen if there was no power supply drawn, because that's a common situation.

Answer (score 1):

The ground symbol shows a common ground. It's a shortcut so you don't need to draw a lot of lines all over the schematic. In bigger schematics it's also done with labeled signals. It's often done for power but also for other signals.

In this schematic we have a current source at the left which supplies a defined current. The current goes trough the resistors and back to the source trough ground.

If you want to know the voltage you use ohms law.
You calcluate the total resistance ( Rtotal = 1/(1/R1+1/R2) and than U = Rtotal * I